# Purpose of Django FieldType Default String Parameter

Tags: django

In the [Django 2.0 Mozilla tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Models), they sometimes use a initial string argument when defining various fieldTypes as part of there new models. For example, they do this with the author variable (ForeignKey FieldType) and isbn (CharField) in the below snippet.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing a book (but not a specific copy of a book).
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    # Foreign Key used because book can only have one author, but authors can have multiple books
    # Author as a string rather than object because it hasn't been declared yet in the file.
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a brief description of the book')
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN',max_length=13, help_text='13 Character <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn">ISBN number</a>')
```

What is the purpose of this string? I looked through the [Django Model Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#field-options) and  could not find an initial string parameter as an option. I assume it is the value used for the column in the database, but that is specified with the optional parameter *db_column*. Any insight is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to specify `ForeingKey` One of them is using direct reference to model. In this case there should be `Author` model in you app.

```
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

The other one is using string name. In this case you can later add your `Author` model in django. Django will not give error. Sometimes you want to create another model later but you also want to reference it now. If this is the case then use String as a parameter version.

```
 author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Now you can create your `Book` model without creating `Author` model.

For `ISBN` field this parameter is `verbose_name`. Name of the column in the table. If you will not specify django automatically create from field name. In this case, programmer wants `isbn` column in the database as capital case `ISBN`. You can find  more details about [verbose_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names) in official documentation.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense for the ForeignKey since we define the Author Class after the Book declaration in the tutorial. How about with the CharField. What does the string 'ISBN' do there since it does not have a dependency?

Comment: Hi @archang31, I edit my answer also for ISBN field.

Answer (score 1):

When we look into the source code of both classes (more specifically, their `__init__()` method), (`ForeignKey` and `CharField`) we could find something like below
**`ForeignKey`**

```
class ForeignKey(ForeignObject):
    ....
    ....

    def __init__(self, to, on_delete=None, related_name=None, related_query_name=None,
                 limit_choices_to=None, parent_link=False, to_field=None,
                 db_constraint=True, **kwargs):
    # code
    # code
```

**`CharField`**
This class is `inherited from` Field` class, so

```
class Field(RegisterLookupMixin):
    ...
    ...
    ... code

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, primary_key=False,
                 max_length=None, unique=False, blank=False, null=False,
                 db_index=False, rel=None, default=NOT_PROVIDED, editable=True,
                 serialize=True, unique_for_date=None, unique_for_month=None,
                 unique_for_year=None, choices=None, help_text='', db_column=None,
                 db_tablespace=None, auto_created=False, validators=(),
                 error_messages=None):
        # code
        # code
```

**Conclusion**
The first parameter to the classes are different in both classes.**`CharField`** takes `verbose_name` as first argument whereas **`ForeignKey`** takes `to` which the raled models name as the first parameter

### Resources

1. [`CharField` source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1033)
2. [`Field` source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L90)
3. [`ForeignKey` source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L759)

   Hope this clear your doubt :)